# Нет ссылки на экземпляр объекта c#

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

```
private PanelWithDoubleBuffer[] mArrayOfPanels;
    public HomePage()
    {            
        mArrayOfPanels = new PanelWithDoubleBuffer[] {lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4, lvl5, lvl6, lvl7, lvl8, lvl9, lvl10 };
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.GameLevel + 1; i++)
        {
            mArrayOfPanels[i].Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

На форме есть 10 панелей, к ним нужно обращаться. Для удобства помещаю их в массив, но при обращении выдает исключение nullpointer.
Если делаю =new ...перед действием, то задаю новую ссылку и уже не могу обратиться. Где инициализировать и как ?)

Comment: `InitializeComponent();`  перемести выше. До вызова этого метода панели ещё не инициализированы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov  Большое спасибо, пора сделать перерыв, такие моменты не замечаю)

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что привязка полей типа `lvl1` к реальным контролам происходит как часть `InitializeComponent`. До вызова `InitializeComponent` все эти поля имеют нулевое значение.

Попробуйте так:

```
public HomePage()
{            
    InitializeComponent();

    mArrayOfPanels = new PanelWithDoubleBuffer[]
    {
        lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4, lvl5, lvl6, lvl7, lvl8, lvl9, lvl10
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.GameLevel + 1; i++)
    {
        mArrayOfPanels[i].Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все предельно ясно

Comment: @DmitryUshkevich: Пожалуйста!